# SSAS Cube reprocessing fails - then succeeds if I try again

Tags: ssas, olap-cube

So I'm basically brand new to the concept of BI, and I've inherited an existing ETL process that is a two step process:

1. Loads the data into a database that is only used by the cube processing
2. Starts off the SSAS cube processing against said database

It seems pretty well isolated, but occasionally (once a week, sometimes twice) it will fail with the following exception:

"Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found"

Now the interesting thing is that:

1. The dimension having the issue is not usually the same one (i.e. there's **no single dimension that consistently has this failure**)
2. **The source table**, when I inspect it, **does actually contain the attribute key** that it says could not be found
3. **If I then immediately reprocess** the dimensions and cubes manually through SSMS, **they reprocess successfully** and without incident.

In both the aforementioned job and when I reprocess them through SSMS, I am using "ProcessFull", so it should be reprocessing them completely.

Has anyone run into such an issue?  I'm scratching my head about it... because if it was a genuine data integrity issue, reprocessing the cube again wouldn't fix it.  What on earth could be happening?  I've been tasked with finding out why this happens, but I can neither reproduce it consistently nor can I point to a data integrity problem as the root cause.

Thanks for any input you can provide!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a simular issue and i found that processing the dimentions before processing the cube worked for me.

Comment: Ah, so instead of doing something like this:
...
<Object>
    <DatabaseID>Database</DatabaseID>
</Object>
<Type>ProcessFull</Type>
...

I should tell it to explicitly process individual dimensions first and then the individual cubes?  I was hoping that the ProcessFull would know to do it in the right order, but I may have been overly optimistic. =)

I can definitely give that a shot... does anyone know why ProcessFull might not process in the right order if this does end up fixing it?

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I had to do.

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a shot and see how it goes... I wish I knew why that doesn't always work however.  I've got a lot to learn about cubes, I think. =(

Usually we're guaranteed to get at least one of these to happen during a 7 day period, so if it doesn't happen by this time next week I'll flag this as the answer.  It'll just take a while for me to verify it... I can't think of a consistent way to reproduce it so I can know more immediately. =(

Comment: I think this is going to do it... I'll comment again if it doesn't, but this looks like it's fixing the issue!

Comment: How did the BI team get it into their heads that this is an acceptable approach to reprocessing individual cubes? The more I use SSAS the more quirks and design blunders I see and the less faith I have in this entire branch of Microsoft's BI services.

Answer (score 1):

You said the package starts the processing, what are the settings for the processing?

I'm wondering if it is processing the dimensions last, that could explain it. That would probably only happen on a full process if the number of transactions and parallelism are unusual. Check the settings on your manual full process, versus the settings on the automated process.

Comment: Aye, I believe this must be what is happening: I'm having a hard time consistently reproducing the issue, but I think that based on what John was saying, SQL Server must be attempting to optimize the processing of the SSAS database and doing it out of order.

For clarification, before I made the change John recommended, I was just telling it to process the database itself with "ProcessFull": I was giving it no specific instructions about what order it should process its individual Cubes and Dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Dimensions should always be processed first.

How else will the cube know how to map things out?

There may have been a sale of a new item that appears in the fact table, but which has not been added to the products dimension, for example. It will not be able to perform the join and will fail.

Comment: Indeed: I guess I just thought that telling it to process the entire database would implicitly mean that dimensions would be processed first (for the exact reasons you mentioned =) ).  From the other responses, it sounds like that assumption was incorrect on my part. =)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen something similar with both AS2005 and AS2008.  We get the Dimension Key not found error, despite the dimensions having been processed.

We load and process dimensions daily.  On the first of the month, new partitions are created.  On the first weekend of the month, after the daily dimension processing, fact tables are loaded and the partitions processed.  All this is done via SSIS.  For several months now, partition processing has been failing.  If we wait a day, let the daily dimension processing run once, the partitions then process OK.  Testing has shown that running ProcessUpdate on one key dimension AFTER a fact table has loaded allows the associated partition to process.  Note that the interaction is specific to each partition and depends on the fact table being loaded.  If we load fact table A, process the dimension, then partition A will process.  If we're late loading fact table B, we'll have to wait for the dimension processing to run again before partition B will process.

It's well known that a dimension ProcessUpdate will invalidate associated partition indexes and aggregations, so there are ties between dimension and partition processing.  I suspect we may be seeing some additional undocumented interaction.